# set object as selected in ngoptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

Im using ngOptions for select directive like

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="users.jobTitle" name="jobTitle" data-ng-options="job as job.value for job in ds.jobTitle" required>
```

im setting default in controller like

```
$scope.users.jobTitle = $scope.ds.jobTitle[0];
```

ds is a json with array jobtitle:

```
"jobTitle":[
  {"id":1,"value":"Service1"},
  {"id":2,"value":"Service2"},
  {"id":3,"value":"Service3"}
],
```

now i'm saving and getting result(console) like

```
jobTitle:Object
       $$hashKey:"object:173"
       id:1
     value:"Service1"
```

now when i'm editing, feeding the service call data like

```
$scope.useredit.jobTitle = data.jobTitle;
```

for

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="useredit.jobTitle" name="jobTitle" data-ng-options="job as job.value for job in ds.jobTitle" required>
</select>
```

its not setting the object as selected , instead sets the null value in first option..
what i have to do ?

Comment: Can you show the exact value in `data.jobTitle` by checking in network tab response or logging to console?

Comment: Object
$$hashKey:"object:67"
id:1
value:"Service1"

Comment: `$scope.useredit.jobTitle` must be part of `ds.jobTitle`.

Comment: when creating new user ... im getting 6 to 7 fields only .. after if they want to edit their information i ask for more info like 20 more fields..so they are seperate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value. This is
>   important to know when binding the select to a model that is an object
>   or a collection.
>
> One issue occurs if you want to preselect an option. For example, if
>   you set the model to an object that is equal to an object in your
>   collection, ngOptions won't be able to set the selection, because the
>   objects are not identical. So by default, you should always reference
>   the item in your collection for preselections, e.g.: $scope.selected =
>   $scope.collection[3].
>
> **Another solution is to use a track by clause**, because then ngOptions
>   will track the identity of the item not by reference, but by the
>   result of the track by expression. For example, if your collection
>   items have an id property, you would track by item.id.

~ Taken from the official [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) regarding ngOptions

I tested it out by using ng-options in separate select boxes and it works.

See demo below.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.ds = {};
      $scope.ds.jobTitle = [{
        "id": 1,
        "value": "Service1"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "Service2"
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "Service3"
      }];

      var data = {
        jobTitle: {
          "id": 1,
          "value": "Service1"
        }
      };

      $scope.useredit = {
        jobTitle: data.jobTitle
      };

    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <br />Without using track by in ngOptions
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="useredit.jobTitle" name="jobTitle" data-ng-options="job as job.value for job in ds.jobTitle" required>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />Using track by in ngOptions
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="useredit.jobTitle" name="jobTitle" data-ng-options="job as job.value for job in ds.jobTitle track by job.id" required>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer .. It worked @alex_andrea . But when i select each option tag, each one gets selected attribute.. is that a problem ?

Comment: You mean when you select one option then all of the other options in that select element gets the "selected" attribute added to them?

Comment: I don't think that's a problem as long as your not trying to do something related to the `selected` atribute. Is the ng-model  properly to the option that you selected?

Comment: Yes its binding perfectly :) . Will let u know if its not ... @alex_andrea

Comment: Btw.,can you mark this as the answer if this helped you. Thanks in advance.:)